# getstream.io: Creating an activity feed that is the union of the feeds of a group of users

Tags: getstream-io

In getsream.io, I would like to create a group of users that all relate to a common theme. Other users should be able to follow the group and see the union of the posts of all the members. As members are added or removed, the feed of the group should change accordingly.

For example, I may have a group called **Springfield**, in which a number of residents from Springfield are members. Anyone can follow **Springfield** to see the combined activity of all members of the group.

Is this possible or do I need to merge the feeds myself?

Comment: It looks like this answer may give me what I am looking for: [Stream hierarchies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64496847/are-stream-hierarchies-possible-in-getstreams-io)